# about Heine-Borel Theorem in a function space

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, functional-analysis

In Pugh's real mathematical analysis. About the Heine-Borel Theorem in a function space, it states that a subset $\epsilon$ $\in C^0$ is compact if and only if it is closed, bounded, and equicontinuous.
For $C^0$ in the book it is the continuous functions mapping from $[a,b]$ to $R$. I am not sure whether it holds for continuous functions mapping compact metric space $M$ to $M$, namely, $C^0[M,M]$?
It will be so useful if we can use it in that sense.

Comment: I think it is also true and the proof are more or less the same. Not sure if one can find a proof though.

Comment: @John I tried to find Heine Borel Theorem in a function space in wiki but I couldn't find it.

Comment: That's more commonly called Arzela Ascoli theorem. But it is still not what you are looking for (but close).

Comment: Indeed, it is probably best to keep the name «Heine-Borel» for the property that a set is compact iff it is closed and bounded.

Comment: @John In our text book and the wiki it all seems we need to take real valued functions. What kind of theorem can I use if I want to show there is a convergent subsequence of a sequence of functions that maps from compact metric space to it self?

Comment: Rather than «use a theorem» you'll need to just follow the steps in the proof of the Ascoli-Arzela theorem, adapted to your situation.

Comment: But it seems that we need the completeness of $R$ to prove the theorem.

Comment: Yes, but now the image is $M$, which is compact (so complete)